# storing percentages into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to store a number of percentages that I've worked out into an array so that I can call it later on to create a pie chart but don't have a clue how to do it. Here is my PHP code so far for working out the percentages:           Thanks for any help in advance!

```
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT book_id, COUNT(*) FROM loan GROUP BY book_id ASC ORDER BY     count(*) DESC LIMIT 10");
$book_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

$step = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $total = $total + $row['COUNT(*)'];
    $i[$step] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
    $step++;
}

for($index = 1; $index <= 10; $index++)
{
    $percentage[$index] = (($i[$index]/$total)*100);
    #$degrees = (($percentage/100)*360);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to store values into an array in PHP? Is the outcome of your calculations a Number?

Comment: Yep, that's right, and yep the outcome of the percentage is an integer.

Comment: What's wrong with this line here `$percentage[$index] = (($i[$index]/$total)*100);` ?

Comment: So, what's wrong with this code?  Does it work?

Comment: @james I know there isn't anything wrong with the code, I was just asking, with this code; how would i store the values of the percentages into an array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It works, but I want to store the values of the percentages (in the loop) into an array.

Comment: As far as I'm aware that is storing the values in an array. The only issue would be the scope of the `$percentage` variable. I would think it would need to be outside the loop.

Comment: @user1930227: You are.  `$percentage` is your array with your percentages.

Comment: @James: PHP has function scope, not block scope.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Cheers - it's a grey area for me! ;)

Comment: @james oh right, however when I call $percentage later on in my code (I'm creating a pie chart), nothing seems to happen, shall I show you the entirety of my code?

Comment: What do you mean by call? You will need to iterate through that array when reading it later (using a `for` loop for instance) to read the values back out (generally).

Comment: @user1930227: If you want.  But, for now, what does `var_dump($percentage)` print out (if you put it after the loop)?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh I see, it's just that when I call $percentage later on in my code, it crashes.

Comment: @James I'm using it later on in another loop to create the arcs of the pie chart, var_dump($percentage) echoes out: "float(5.8823529411765) 
" which happens to be the last value of percentage.

Comment: @user1930227: Are you modifying `$percentage` elsewhere?

Comment: @RocketHazmat This is what I do with $percentage after... 
$angle = 0;

for ($index=0, $count=count($percentage); $index<$count; $index++)
{
$degrees = (($percentage[$index]/100)*360);
$color = imagecolorallocate($pie,mt_rand(20,255),mt_rand(20,255),mt_rand(20,255));

imagefilledarc($pie,100,100,125,125,$angle,($angle+$degrees),$color,IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledrectangle($pie,250,(50+(25*($index+1))),275,(75+(25*($index+1))),$color);
imagestring($pie,$font,276,(55+(25*($index+1))),$percentage[$index]."  %",$black);

$angle+=$degrees;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're asking, just substitute the variables for real ones:

```
array_push($array, $value);
// This will add "$value" on to the end of $array, i.e the last element
```

It can also be done much simpler:

```
$array[] = $value;
```

Updated code:

```
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT book_id, COUNT(*) FROM loan GROUP BY book_id ASC ORDER BY       count(*) DESC LIMIT 10");
$book_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

$step = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $total = $total + $row['COUNT(*)'];
    $i[$step] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
    $step++;
}

$percentage_array = array();

for($index = 1; $index <= 10; $index++)
{
    array_push($percentage_array, (($i[$index]/$total)*100));
    #$degrees = (($percentage/100)*360);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So will this save the 10 percentages I've worked out into an array?

Comment: Yep, I've added the updated code to my post. Please tell me if that works. (The percentages will be stored in the `$percentage_array` array )

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working, but maybe It's just me, if I wanted to echo the array what would I type?

Comment: `print_r($percentage_array)` or `$percentage_array[0]` 0 is the index of the element you want to display....

Comment: more reading about how to work with arrays here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Still no output :( Thanks for your help though! Much appreciated.

Comment: Done :) Although, I have a new issue though (sorry) , since I'm creating a pie chart with these percentages, I can't seem to get the pie chart to display and work with what I've calculated :(